# How I can move Symfony2 SonataAdminBundle from "/admin" route to "admin" subdomain

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I need to move admin to separate subdomain on Symfony2. How I should configure my routes and security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the security part you can easily restrict the security firewall to a specific host (since Symfony 2.4) as described in this [official announcement](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-restrict-security-firewalls-to-specific-hosts) and the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/firewall_restriction.html#restricting-by-host).

Here you can see an example of a **admin** firewall configuration for the domain *admin.your-domain.com*

```
security:
    firewalls:
        admin:
            pattern:    ^/
            host:       admin\.your-domain\.com
            http_basic: true
```

For the routing part you could either refactor your **admin**-routes to point to **/** and use the **host** matching in the routes as described in the [official documentation of the routing component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html#using-host-matching-of-imported-routes).

Here is an example of a route configuration with the host matching option:

```
admin_dashboard:
    path: /
    host: "admin.your-domain.com"
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Dashboard:homepage }
```

Or your could rewrite the urls `www.your-domain.com/admin` to `admin.your-domain.com` using the web server configuration. This is an example for apache:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?your-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) http://admin.your-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Awesome! :) But you forgot about security changes

Comment: do you mean the acl settings?